# Batch job on windows server 2008

Tags: .net, windows, cron

I need to setup a batch job that monitor an SQL table regularly (let's say every minute) and check if there is data to process. If there is then it should call a script to process the data. Before calling the processing script, it also needs to check if the same process has been happening. If the same process is currently going on then it stops, otherwise just process the data.

In LAMPP environment, I would just create a PHP script to do the processing, setup a cron job to call the script and set the cron job to run every minute.

What's the best approach to do this in .NET environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a console application, then schedule it using Windows Task Scheduler.

Alternatively, create a Windows Service that runs continually, and either use a timer to run a handler at an interval, or use a `SqlDependency` to run your handler whenever the table changes.

Comment: thanks SLaks. Is there any pro and cons between console application and windows service? which one will be automatically started when the box was rebooted?

Comment: Services are generally run at startup.  Console applications aren't, but you can make them run at intervals using Task Scheduler.  I recommend writing a service.

Comment: thanks ... looking at tutorial for creating a windows service now.